# Check whether the scrollview is scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-layout, touch, scrollview

There is a scrollview contain a linearlayout with set of text views .

Then I have set a timer run each 0.1 second, if the scrollview is not ontouch , then run some function

Here is how I create the timer

```
handler = new Handler();

r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        s.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //run some function if not on touch;

                handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
            }
        });
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
```

The problem is how to check whether scrollview is ontouch at that time, there is a setOnTouchListener, but can it check ontouch at specific time ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to achieve; knowing that can help me help you. Are you using the `Runnable` to check if the `ScrollView` is scrolling?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more wt you want to do?

Comment: sure, runnable is to scroll the scrollview to particular position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the scrollview on touch in Boolean variable, update its value inside onTouch and keep a track of the flag to do what u like.

```
like say -
//global declaration
Public Boolean scrollviewFlag=false;

//inside onCreate activity

Below is the code to check the touch event of scrollView.

 ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    scroll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && tochedView != null) {
                Log.i("Touche", "ScrollView ACTION_UP"); 
                srollviewFlag=true;               
                return true;
            }
            srollviewFlag=false;     
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: only on touch it is true, but is there any "not on touch" event? thanks for helping

Comment: after every interval of time as u said, call the setOnTouchListener and check the boolean flag value whether true or not.